# Command line automation for bates stamping a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation

Goal: build a command line script that would bates-stamp pdf files.

What libraries (preferably python for use across Windows / MacOS / Ubuntu) would form a good starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing stuff like that in Python isn't supported very well. You might be able to do it with PyPDF. Here's a link to a script that has an example of sorts:

- http://coils.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/coils/coils/file/9d6c304dd405/src/coils/logic/workflow/actions/doc/watermark.py

You might find the following useful as well:

- http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-May/623756.html
- [Generating & Merging PDF Files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263263/generating-merging-pdf-files-in-python)